# Need help with this php function

Tags: php, arrays, function

Here's my php code

```
$values = array(

        'php' => 'php hypertext processor',

        'other' => array(
            'html' => 'hyper text markup language',
            'css' => 'cascading style sheet',
            'asp' => 'active server pages',
        )

);


function show($id='php', $id2='others') {

    global $values;

    if(isset($id2)) {
        $title = $values[$id];
    }
    elseif(empty($id2)) {
        $title = $values[$id][$id2];
    }

    return $title;

}
```

when i do

```
echo show('php');
```

it shows "php hypertext processor"

but when i do

```
echo show('other','asp');
```

it doesnt work properly, it should display "active server pages"

Whats the error i am making? Can anybody help me out?

Comment: try to add exceptionhandling in your function because your function is also open to receive nothing at all (two times null for example) in that case you'll get an error cause title doesn't exist...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing the check the wrong way around.

Also, the `empty` call is somewhat redundant. I would recommend this:

```
if(!empty($id2)) {
        $title = $values[$id][$id2];

    }
    else {
       $title = $values[$id]; 
    }
```

Comment: if i do this, the second one works perfectly but the first one "echo show('php');" doesn't, it just shows "p"

Comment: @Roccos ah yes, you need to set the default of `$id2` to `null`, not `others`

Comment: it says missing argument 2, but displays correct text after showing error.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you are always entering the first part of your if statement as you set a default value for $id2 in your function declaration and your logic is slightly wonky.  Try:

```
function show($id='php', $id2) {

    global $values;

    if(isset($id2)) {
        $title = $values[$id][$id2];

    }
    elseif(empty($id2)) {
        $title = $values[$id];
    }

    return $title;

}
```

This way if $id2 is set then it should pull out from the second array and default to the first if empty.

Comment: if i do this, it says missing argument two, but the rest works perfectly.

Comment: OK, then just change the function declaration to show($id='php', $id2=NULL).

Answer (score 0):

Well I believe your fundamental logic is wrong: Look if you are setting both variables with a default value, this logic of urs..

```
 if(isset($id2)) {
    $title = $values[$id];
}
elseif(empty($id2)) {
    $title = $values[$id][$id2];
}
```

Boils down to

```
$title = $values[$id];
```

Better you try to keep no default values and rebuild the logic.